# Glimpse SQL shows select top 2 very often

Tags: entity-framework, glimpse

See in this example

[image]

Now im not doing a top 2, im just doing a simple entity find, so im a bit at a loss as to why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are more than likely using `SingleOrDefault` or possibly `Find`. These methods work by selecting the top two rows. It then makes sure that only one row is returned. If more than one element was returned then it will throw an exception.

How else would it know if there was more than one match?

```
// If there were two Products with a ProductName of Widget then the code would throw an exception.
context.Products.SingleOrDefault(i => i.ProductName == "Widget");

// If there were two Products with a ProductId of 1234 then the code would throw an exception.
context.Products.Find(1234);
```

Comment: Thanks didnt realise we were using that, we normally use FirstOrDefault but your right we are, will further investigate why. Thanks. And thanks to everyone else for the downvotes.